# Issue with content access and multilingual system

Tags: users, i18n-l10n

I have a multilingual website using English, Arabic and French. 2 days ago I noticed that anytime when I clicked on `node/add/*` for the English section, it returns an access denied page. And that is just for English (the other languages are fine and nothing wrong with them).

I use the [Content Access](https://www.drupal.org/project/content_access) module but even after I uninstalled it the issue remains the same.

I'm using Drupal version 7.32 and [I18n](https://www.drupal.org/project/i18n) 7.x-1.11.

Does anyone have an idea about this issue?

Comment: What's the language-decision priority in your environment?  Path-prefix based or else?  Are all the languages treated equally or not?  For example, in default, the path-prefix for the default language is null and so is different from the others.

Comment: What exactly do you mean with "clicked on node/add/* for the english section"? Can you edit your question to better explain which links or urls you use to add an English translation for some existing node?

Answer (score 0):

I see 2 possible explanations for your issue, as further detailed below. Consider checking both of them to see if either one of them apply in this case.

### Cookie problem

It is possibly an issue with a cookie. So try the same scenario usiing another browser. If with that browser the problem does not occur, then it is probably a cookie problem. In that case, just delete the session cookie in the browser where the problem occurs. Then check if the issue is resolved.

### Site may be hacked

Since the version of this Drupal site is **7.32**, it might simply be that your site was hacked. Refer to [SA-CORE-2014-005](https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2014-005) (posted a week before this question was asked ...) for some more details.

For way more details about that, and possible approaches to do more research on that, refer to [Drupal SA-CORE-2014-005 - How to tell if my server / sites were compromised?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/133996), which also suggests to use the [Drupalgeddon](https://www.drupal.org/project/drupalgeddon) module.