# Drupal Sending tons of Spam email

Tags: 7, advertising

Apparently one of the modules installed on my drupal site has been sending SPAM emails from my server as in (name)_(lastname)@(myservername).com , it managed to send 1000 email and queue 97,000 emails only in the first day..

At first, based on the email details, I figured it was being sent from a PHP page called diff.php under `/sites/all/modules/contrib/libraries/tests/libraries/diff.php`, so I deleted the whole tests folder, but now the emails are heading directly from my root site..
I have installed Hacked! to a development copy, and here's a copy of the results:
[image]

Does it seem like a module issue? should I re-install the changed modules?

Comment: In order to avoid similar issues in the future, go to /admin/reports/updates/settings and add your email so you will get notifications whenever a new security update is available. Don't forget to set up a cron job. Try to do the security updates as soon as possible and make frequent backups of your database.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The version of core you're running - 7.30 - is *extremely* vulnerable.  As long as you're running any version of core prior to 7.32, your site will *remain* vulnerable.  The vulnerability will allow changing modules (which *can* be discovered with the [**Hacked!**](https://www.drupal.org/project/hacked) module), putting executable PHP in the database (which *can not* be discovered with **Hacked!**), and injecting malicious shell scripts (which *can not* be discovered with **Hacked!**).

**Simply replacing Drupal core and modules with non-hacked versions will not remove backdoors.**

Just going through the changed modules and reinstalling them will *not* do.  At this point, even if you replace everything, the intruder have probably infected your database with exploits, as well as having installed several well-hidden backdoors to your site at shell level.

The best recourse is to delete your entire site an rebuild it from scratch on a clean vhost, then restore its contents from a backup made prior to Oct. 15, 2014.

Read this SA to understand the severity of this vulnerability: https://www.drupal.org/SA-CORE-2014-005. Also read:

- https://www.drupal.org/node/2357241
- http://www.linuxjournal.com/content/drupageddon-sql-injection-database-abstraction-and-hundreds-thousands-web-sites

If you're unable to delete the site and restore from backup, read this about recovering: [Drupal SA-CORE-2014-005 - How to tell if my server / sites were compromised?](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/133996/drupal-sa-core-2014-005-how-to-tell-if-my-server-sites-were-compromised/134501).

*After* you have cleaned up your site, to be alerted if this happens again, consider installing [**File integrity check**](https://www.drupal.org/project/file_integrity). This module will monitor the integrity of almost all files on your site and send you an email if it detects that file integrity is breached.

Answer (score 0):

yes - start in a new folder and install everything new. (you can try to copy the unchanged modules from your old installation - but i wouldn't suggest that)

take care of any customizations made to core or contributed modules (actually, this is bad practice ..) - so , first keep your code and check back there if something does not work.