# I can't open a block link

Tags: commerce

While opening a block link in the backend, I get the following error:

> Fatal error: Cannot redeclare l2464256() (previously declared in C:\wamp\www\xxx\modules\block\block.tpl.php:1) in C:\wamp\www\xxx\modules\block\block.tpl.php on line 1

Why does this happen? How can I fix it?

Comment: Welcome to Drupal Answers :) Unfortunately it's impossible to debug a site to which we don't have access. You'll need to find the offending code, decide what it's doing, whether it's malicious (the name of that function is pretty suspicious, could suggest your site has been compromised), and how best to deal with it when you have that information. For reference, in case it is related to a breach/hack, we have [this post](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/133996/drupal-sa-core-2014-005-how-to-tell-if-my-server-sites-were-compromised) which contains a lot of useful info