# Accessing Login page shows You are not authorized to access this page

Tags: users

Till about an hour ago my Drupal 7 site was working fine. But now when I access the login page (/user) I get an **You are not authorized to access this page**

So I checked the node_access table and I see a record for anonymous users - 0 0 all 1 0 0

I checked the sessions table and it didn't seem to be corrupted. But nevertheless cleared the records. But I am still unable to access the login page

The last time we applied a module update was 10 days back so I don't think its got to do anything with the module code written by us.

I am at my wits end! Have anyone of you faced a similar issue?

EDIT 21st Oct 2014 : A link that explains the exploit - [is here](https://www.getpantheon.com/blog/what-we-are-seeing-drupal-sa-2014-005)

Comment: Depending on the Drupal version you are on there was a severe anonymous hack. We had the same issue on one of our sites where I work. We looked into the database tables and noticed that the menu_router table had access callback changed for the user entry. I would start looking there.

Comment: We are finding out that there are more injections in the tables... not just on the /user menu_router. If I were you, I would restore my database from a backup file. Hopefully you have a nightly backup of your database.

Comment: I found that the menu_router table had the access_callback set to  **php_eval** for the /user path. Updated it to 1.

Comment: I have a backup of 15th Oct. Restoring it and comparing the Drupal tables

Comment: I just confirmed with the operations team and this is also what they had found. However, they found it in more tables besides the menu_router table. So if you have a backup that you can go do without losing a lot of data; That would be the way to go.

Comment: Ok cool, good luck!

Comment: @FatGuyLaughing - Please post this as an answer so that I can accept it. My site works now. Updating menu_router table to set the access_callback to 1 for the /user path worked.

Comment: Just curious as to how the injection could have been accomplished.

Comment: @sridharpandurangiah Very, very easily: http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/133795/what-kind-of-attacks-does-the-patch-for-sa-core-2014-005-drupal-7-32-prevent

Answer (score 1):

You are logged in, and need to logout.